# Sequelize: escape string in a literal string

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js, sql-injection

I can use [`literal`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-literal) in Sequelize to manually build a SQL query part:

```
sequelize.literal(`"foo".bar ILIKE '%baz%'`)
```

But if I want to add a var in this literal block, I now introduce SQL injection vulnerability:

```
sequelize.literal(`"foo".name ILIKE '%${myVar}%'`)
```

Is there a Sequelize way to protect variables in literal blocks?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use `escape`:

```
const escapedSearch = sequelize.escape(`%${myVar}%`);
sequelize.literal(`"foo".name ILIKE ${escapedSearch}`);
```

See: https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-escape

Comment: `sequelize.escape is not a function` tested as of 6.14.0.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `replacements` and `?` to avoid sql injections:

```
sequelize.query(`"foo".name ILIKE '%?%'`,
  { replacements: [myVar], type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
description = {
    $like: sequelize.literal(`${myVar} ESCAPE '\\'`)
};
```